# Generating random numbers and setting them as variables to use later

Tags: php

I am wanting to generate a random number and be able to use that number through-out the whole program. At the moment I am using $random = rand($min, $max); but each time I call the variable $random it changes. Is there a way to make that constant.

Comment: That isn't how PHP works. If the value of `$random` is changing, it's because you're changing it.

Comment: I am using $random, but it still changes.

Comment: You can make $random a global variable http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I agree with meagear. Post the rest of your code so we can see what else your are doing with $random.

Comment: Are you talking about storing a value between 2 separate invocations of a script? Because that's what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) are for.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use `$random` like this:

```
$random = rand(0,10000);

echo "$random\n"; 
echo "$random\n"; //same number
```

If you have `$random` inside of a function, then `$random` will change each time.